# Could not find function or function reference financial

Tags: pine-script

I am just trying out Pine Script for the first time, and can't make this work – which should be trivial according to other examples.

```
study("Price to Operating Income", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)
op_income = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "OPER_INCOME", "FQ")
price_op_income = close/op_income
plot(price_op_income)
```

> Could not find function or function reference financial

Is this simply because Operating Income is not available for Pine Script in the free version of TradingView, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the `//@version=4` tag in the beginning of your script.
`financial()` is a function that's available as of Pine script version 4.

```
//@version=4
study("Price to Operating Income", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)

op_income = financial(syminfo.tickerid, "OPER_INCOME", "FQ")
price_op_income = close/op_income

plot(price_op_income)
```